# Convert dd mmm yyyy to datetime in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

In our database, we have date value as "12 JAN 2021" and we need to convert it as 2021-01-12 12:05:11. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Where does the time part come from? What did you try? Did you have a look in documentations?

Comment: Its just an example.. We need datetime in that format.. U can ignore time part for now

Answer (score 0):

In case the value in the database is a datetime you can just format it using
`FORMAT(YourDate,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`
or if it is possible change the datetime format on the machine running your SQL instance.

Worst case scenario you would need to split the value using substring and combine it into a string that matches the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Insert date to mysql database.
`$added_on  =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` //2020-10-22 13:52:26